# After updating Spring Boot from 3.1 to 3.2, getting org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@57f8208e does not have a name

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

After updating Spring Boot from 3.1 to 3.2, even added the -parameters flag for Java compilation. Despite this, getting After updating Spring Boot from 3.1 to 3.2, even added the -parameters flag for Java compilation.
Despite this, getting org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@57f8208e does not have a name

`PeroidDuration` is a class used from `org.threeten.extra` dependency , it has a private constructor this attribute we used in an entity/Document
It is saved successfully in db but on fetching getting following error :

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@57f8208e does not have a name
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:61)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:98)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:512)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:480)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2359)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2168)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1934)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:620)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:537)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:514)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:480)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2359)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2168)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1934)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:620)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:537)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:514)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:480)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:416)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.project(MappingMongoConverter.java:314)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ProjectingReadCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3322)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2912)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2617)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.doFind(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:177)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.all(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:135)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.lambda$getExecution$3(AbstractMongoQuery.java:189)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:147)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:119)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:129)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy111.findByTenantIdInAndRuleId(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
```

Comment: You need the `-parameters` on the compiler if using maven and the spring boot starter this should already be added. However in your case you are using an external dependency (which seems like an outdated one as well) which doesn't have the additional information.